# Unity: Ball drops after colliding with the star

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity, rigid-bodies

I am working on a game in which there is a ball that has to be thrown by the player in such a way that it should collect the stars placed in the air before hitting the goal without falling on the ground. The stars are stationary. Stars (no rigidbody) have a box collider attached to them and the ball has a sphere collider and a rigidbody ("Use Gravity" checked and "Is Kinematic" unchecked) attached. The Angular drag on the ball is set to 0. The ball when collides at the corner of the star works fine but when collides with the body of the star, falls off straight to the ground instead of moving in the direction in which it is thrown. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some code. Also, is your stars collider a trigger? Sounds to me that you want the star to be a trigger and not a collider

Comment: You're right, Thanks! It had to be a trigger. My problem got resolved after changing it to trigger.